# Problem with addEventListener and passing function

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

My problem is that when I clicked one of this boxes function mark is call of 9 times. 
Why is this happening ? I also add that boxes have 9 elements.

```
export function battle(app, mod, player) {

  const newHtml = html.replace("mode", mod.toUpperCase());

  app.innerHTML = newHtml;

  const boxes = document.querySelectorAll('.battle div');

  if (mod = 'single') {
    boxes.forEach(elem => addEventListener('click', (e) => {
      mark(e.target, player);
    }, false));
  }
  if (mod = 'multi') {

  }
}
```

Comment: Boxes contains 9 element, so in the forEach loop, every box will have an event listener with the same function handler

Comment: @QuangThái — That doesn't explain why one click triggers 9 function calls

Comment: You want to attach the event listener like this: elem.addEventListener

Comment: If you want something for people to click on, use a `<button>`, not a `<div>`. You'll create all sorts of accessibility problems if you use an element that isn't designed to be interactive.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `addEventListener` which is akin to `window.addEventListener`, so you are attaching 9 event handlers to the `window` object. A click anywhere will trigger all of them.

You need to add the event listener to the boxes.

```
elem => elem.addEventListener
```